# Why do I get this WCF error when 'GET'ing?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, uritemplate

I have written the method contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "TestEchoWithTemplate/{message}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string TestEchoWithTemplate(string s);
```

and the implementing method:

```
  public string TestEchoWithTemplate(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }
```

When I browse to the Url:

> http://localhost:52587/VLSContentService.svc/rest/TestEchoWithTemplate/HelloWorld

I get the following error:

> Operation 'TestEchoWithTemplate' in
>   contract 'IVLSContentService' has a
>   UriTemplate that expects a parameter
>   named 'MESSAGE', but there is no input
>   parameter with that name on the
>   operation.

The following produce the same error:

http://localhost:52587/VLSContentService.svc/rest/TestEchoWithTemplate/MESSAGE=HelloWorld
http://localhost:52587/VLSContentService.svc/rest/TestEchoWithTemplate?MESSAGE=HelloWorld

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the template as

```
"TestEchoWithTemplate/{s}"
```

Since your method has `s` instead of `message`. Alternatively change the name to `message` in your interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "TestEchoWithTemplate/{message}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string TestEchoWithTemplate(string message);
```